# Domain of $\log_2\log_3\log_2\log_3\log_2x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I'm working on some math questions for a scholarship. I'm having a tough time as it seems to be tough for me. Please help me out

> The function $\log_2\log_3\log_2\log_3\log_2x$ has the interval $x>?$ as its maximum domain on real numbers.

The key answer is $x>512$ and I have no idea how to go about with the answer.

Comment: Hint: the log of a negative number is undefined, so you must ensure that every quantity whose log is taken is positive...

Comment: Does the scholarship permit seeking outside help?

Comment: Thanks for the tips

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Work from the outside, peeling away the logarithms:
$$\log_2\log_3\log_2\log_3\log_2x\in\mathbb R\implies\log_3\log_2\log_3\log_2x>0$$
$$\log_3\log_2\log_3\log_2x>0\implies\log_2\log_3\log_2x>1$$
$$\log_2\log_3\log_2x>1\implies\log_3\log_2x>2$$
$$\log_3\log_2x>2\implies\log_2x>9$$
$$\log_2x>9\implies x>512$$
This works because the logarithm is a strictly increasing function.

Comment: It really helped. Thanks a lot for the support. I hope I can prepare well